# Tomcat 8: So many opened ports

Tags: java, tomcat, talend, ports

Just installed Tomcat v8.0.23 on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
svntac-002:tomcat8 root# java -cp lib/catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
Server built:   May 19 2015 14:58:38 UTC
Server number:  8.0.23.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.2.0-67-virtual
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_80-b15
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

And seeing seeing a lot of open connections for Java like these:

```
svntac-002:tomcat8 root# netstat -ntpl|grep java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33103           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26882/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33359           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26882/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57647           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26882/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54255           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26882/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49295           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26882/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49039           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26882/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41583           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26882/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44591           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26882/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39279           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26882/java
```

In fact, `321` open connections at the time of writing:

```
svntac-002:tomcat8 root# netstat -ntpl|grep java|wc -l
321
```

Does it sound right? Is it some sort of bug in that Tomcat version that I'm experiencing or missing something? I'm running `Talend` TAC on this server (hence, installed/deployed `org.talend.administrator.war`) and after a while, the TAC becomes completely unresponsive. How do I debug this? Thanks in advance!